# Simplicial Homotopy Theory (References)

Tags: reference-request

I'd like to know some good references,introductory or not in Simplicial Homotopy Theory.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Goerss and Jardine's book](http://books.google.com.sg/books/about/Simplicial_Homotopy_Theory.html?id=ED1bVh5K-5YC&redir_esc=y) is very good.

Answer (score 3):

"Simplicial Objects in Algebraic Topology" by Peter May is a good one.